# Update a single field to array in mongodb using JAVA

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents of below format:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("559bae5df3fcf46e468a9779"),
        "CPF" : "129-87-716",
        "NAME" : "Donald Carver",
        "CONTACT" : 1827626847,
        "ADDRESS" : "937 Hamburg Path",
        "EMAIL_ADDRESS" : "constpherd@yah00.net",
        "CARDS" : {
                "CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER" : "1678-768-420-4188",
                "CARD_TYPE" : "IVISA",
                "EXPIRY_DATE" : "Mon May 21 15:23:53 IST 2018"
        }
}
```

I want to update an array of document  .

```
"TRANSACTIONS":[{"TRANSACTION_NUMBER":"1","TRANSACTION_DATE":"07/07/2015","BANK_ID":"200","AMOUNT":100},
                {"TRANSACTION_NUMBER":"2","TRANSACTION_DATE":"08/07/2015","BANK_ID":"0","AMOUNT":200},
                {"TRANSACTION_NUMBER":"3","TRANSACTION_DATE":"06/07/2015","BANK_ID":"200","AMOUNT":100}
                       ]
       }
```

And it should look like below:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("559bae5df3fcf46e468a9779"),
        "CPF" : "129-87-716",
        "NAME" : "Donald Carver",
        "CONTACT" : 1827626847,
        "ADDRESS" : "937 Hamburg Path",
        "EMAIL_ADDRESS" : "constpherd@yah00.net",
        "CARDS" : {
                "CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER" : "1678-768-420-4188",
                "CARD_TYPE" : "IVISA",
                "EXPIRY_DATE" : "Mon May 21 15:23:53 IST 2018"
        }
        "TRANSACTIONS":[{"TRANSACTION_NUMBER":"1","TRANSACTION_DATE":"07/07/2015","BANK_ID":"200","AMOUNT":100},
                        {"TRANSACTION_NUMBER":"2","TRANSACTION_DATE":"08/07/2015","BANK_ID":"0","AMOUNT":200},
                        {"TRANSACTION_NUMBER":"3","TRANSACTION_DATE":"06/07/2015","BANK_ID":"200","AMOUNT":100}
                       ]
       }
}
```

This is what I am trying to do it using java:

```
String[] creditcard = line.split(cvsSplitBy);



        DBObject listItem = new BasicDBObject("TRANSACTION", new BasicDBObject("TRANSACTION_NUMBER",creditcard[1])
                                                                       .append("TRANSACTION_DATE",creditcard[2])
                                                                       .append("TRANSACTION_TYPE",creditcard[3])
                                                                       .append("BANK_ID",creditcard[4])
                                                                       .append("AMOUNT",creditcard[5])
                                                                                );


        DBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject("$push", listItem);
        userimage.update(new BasicDBObject().append("CARDS.CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER", creditcard[0]), updateQuery);
```

The program updates one row when I run for the first time.When I run second time the program does not insert any doc into the array ... 
I am not able to find out the logical error in the program..

Comment: It may be problem with `update` `append` try this ` userimage.update(new BasicDBObject(), updateQuery);` or check by printing `creditcard[0]` value which either not matched with `CARDS.CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER`